# How can I determine if an Outlook folder is public?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-object-model

I need a way to determine if an Outlook folder is public.  I suspect there is some property Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook that will allow me to do it, but I can't find it.

Comment: Outlook folders don't seem to have a "public" properties but they do have permissions. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Public folders are an exchange thing.  Not sure if the Outlook OM would let you access it.  I know for sure that EWS (Exchange Web Service) allows access to public folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get at the `IMsgStore` interface associated with the folder in question (sorry, no idea how to do that with pure C# - I recommend [Redemption](http://dimastr.com/redemption/)) you could query the `PR_MDB_PROVIDER` property to see whether it is `pbExchangeProviderPublicGuid`.

**Update** based on your comment to KG's answer:

If you want to filter out the contacts that are inside your primary mailbox, just compare their `StoreID` with that of your default inbox folder - or simply don't enumerate folders from any other stores to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Exchange Web Service, specifically the FindFolder operation (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563918(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa493892(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) for some MSDN descriptions).

Although, from the looks of it, there is no specific property that identifies whether or not the folder is "public", like @RedDeckWins mentions.

**UPDATE**

If you are not specifically required to use managed C# for this, you can use the Powershell Exchange Cmdlets (check this out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788135(EXCHG.80).aspx)). Specifically, this command might be helpful:

```
Get-PublicFolder -Recurse | Format-List Name
```

Powershell is pretty easy to use by itself, but it can also be called from C#, if the server your code is running on has it installed (which, for most modern boxes, should).

If you **ARE** limited to C#, take a look at this StackOverflow question: [List of email address to public folders in exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661647/list-of-email-address-to-public-folders-in-exchange)

Comment: I want to enumerate the folders and pull out the contacts, but just the local ones, not the contacts on the exchange server.  It seems odd that I can't find a good way to determine if the contacts are local or remote on the exchange server when I enumerate through them.

Comment: See my update. Are you limited to ONLY C#, or can you use Powershell? The tools included with Exchange might help here greatly.

Comment: @Greg: See the update to my answer: If you only want the Contacts folders inside your primary mailbox (*not* the Public ones), just compare their `StoreID`s or simply limit your search to the local store.